# Why we need advanced versions in SQL Server and explain specific features it included with simple example

Tags: sql-server

Why we keep moving from SQL Server 2000 to 2005 to 2008 to 2012 to 2016 to recent application of SQL Server? Answer me simply with example.. and kindly tell features included in each version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd question, odd answer :
[Obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolescence)

By the way, if you wish to ask for support for unsupported solutions good luck.
Here is the official Microsoft post on [SQL Server versions supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/plan-design/configs/support-for-sql-server-versions).

Another reason, is the inter-compatibility between application versions and maintenance cost.

By the way, updating products allow flaws to be fixed, security flaws for example.
Countless the performance upgrades, etc...

To make short : **upgrade your products !**

Here is the [list of features for SQL 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-supported-features-for-sql-server-2016).
And [what's new for SQL 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2016).

Here the list of [features for SQL 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc645993(SQL.120).aspx).
Here the list of [features for SQL 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx).
Here the list of [features for SQL 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thank You. It might seems odd questions. But as a beginner in SQL server your answers are more valuable.